# OK to board plane? Indian H1B holder travelling to Dubai on Virgin Atlantic

Tags: indian-citizens, uae, visas-on-arrival, h1b-visas, virgin-atlantic

I plan to fly USA to Dubai on Virgin Atlantic (via London Heathrow). I will be staying in Dubai for 6 days. I hold an H1B visa.

Since Indians with US visas can get visa on arrival in Dubai, I have not applied for a pre-issued visa for my trip. However, I am now concerned that most airlines other than Emirates are not aware of this rule and might disallow me from boarding the aircraft.

Any suggestions on whether I should be worried about Virgin Atlantic not letting me board at Heathrow? How can I get a confirmation that I am ok to fly with them?

Answer (score 4):

Airlines use a database called Timatic to check visa requirements.

The timatic entry for the UAE, Visa section, Visa issuance subsection, states:

> - Nationals of India with a normal passport valid for a  minimum of 6 months from the arrival date with a visa issued by the USA which is valid for a minimum of 6 months can obtain a visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 14 days. They can apply to extend their stay for an additional 14 days.
> - Nationals of India with a normal passport valid for a minimum of 6 months from the arrival date with a residence permit issued by the USA or a European Union Member State which is valid for a minimum of 6 months can obtain a visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 14 days. They can apply to extend their stay for an additional 14 days.

Note that this will most probably be checked at the origin rather than during transit. Also, pay attention to the 6 months rule.

Comment: Perfect answer! It doesn't depend on the airline (FWIW check-in agents usually don't belong to an airline anyway). That said, it will also be checked at the gate at Heathrow